# Why do I get EOFException when deserializing an encrypted object?

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption

I am writing a serialized and encrypted object to a database via encrypted ByteArrayOutputStream into a Large Object. I can retrieve this Large Object, but I cannot deserialize it.

Here is my code for writing:

```
public void addMessages(int ID, List<Message> messages) {

    ObjectOutput output = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(CryptoHandler.encryptedStream(baos));
    output.writeObject(messages);
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    output.close();
    baos.close();
    getMessages(ID, bais);
}
```

And here is for reading:

```
public List<Message> getMessages(int ID, ByteArrayInputStream bais) {

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectInput oi = CryptoHandler.decryptedObjectStream(bais);
    messages = (List<Message>) oi.readObject(); //here is where i get the EOFException
}
```

The encryption works fine with file stream, so therotically it should work here too.

**UPDATE:**

As sugested, I linked the output and the input skipping the DB, and I get the same error. I deleted the DB related code and updated the remaining to keep the question clean.

Here is my code to encrypt the stream:

```
public static CipherOutputStream encryptedStream(OutputStream out) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
        return new CipherOutputStream(out, pbeCipher);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CryptoHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }//Much more catches here...
}
public static ObjectInputStream decryptedObjectStream(InputStream in) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
        return new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(in, pbeCipher));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CryptoHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } //Much more catches here...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an ObjectInputStream instead of ObjectInput into the chain?

Comment: Does it work if you link the output of your write+encrypt code directly into read+decrypt code without storing it into the database?

Comment: @AdamK Cyprtohandler.decryptedObjectStream returns an ObjetInputStream

Comment: @Oleg Estekhin Good idea, I make the unit test and I will update the question.

Comment: You should of course close the ObjectOutputStream *before* getting the byte array from the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I looked at your code again, and found that, you should only close the ObjectOutputStream immediately after writing through it:

```
public void addMessages(int ID, List<Message> messages) {

    ObjectOutput output = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(CryptoHandler.encryptedStream(baos));
    output.writeObject(messages);
    output.close(); // it shouldn't remain open after writing the object
    bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    getMessages(ID, bais);
}
```

But i would also suggest you saving baos.toByteArray() into a byte[] instead of giving a ByteArrayInputStream as argument. You should pass the byte array instead and making ByteArrayInputStream at the getMessages function to make the code more readable.

Comment: baos.close() is redundant.